# Pauli-Jordan 4d version

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I don' understand a passage to get from 3D version
$$
Δ(x)=\frac {-i}{(2π)^3}∫\frac {d^3p}{2\omega_k} (e^{−ipx}-e^{ipx})
$$
to 4D
$$
Δ(x)=\frac {-i}{(2π)^3}∫d^4p \,ε(p^0)δ(k^2−m^2)e^{−ipx}
$$

To add the fourth dimension in the integral, the trick is to use Dirac's delta $\delta(x)$ so that $(e^{−ipx}-e^{ipx})$ can be written

$$
(e^{−i(\omega_k t - \vec p \cdot \vec r)}-e^{i(\omega_k t - \vec p \cdot \vec r)})=∫dp^0 (\delta(p^0 - \omega_k) e^{−i(p^0 t - \vec p \cdot \vec r)}-\delta(p^0 - \omega_k)e^{i(p^0 t - \vec p \cdot \vec r)})
$$
then I see (for example in Walter Greiner, Joachim Reinhardt - Field Quantization, p. 101)
$$
(e^{−i(\omega_k t - \vec p \cdot \vec r)}-e^{i(\omega_k t - \vec p \cdot \vec r)})=∫dp^0 (\delta(p^0 - \omega_k) e^{−i(p^0 t - \vec p \cdot \vec r)}-\delta(p^0 + \omega_k)e^{-i(p^0 t - \vec p \cdot \vec r)})
$$
**That is, inverting the sign in the fixed term in the second $\delta$ you can invert ALL the argument of the exponent, not just of $p^0$ as I was expecting, I mean $e^{i(-p^0 t - \vec p \cdot \vec r)}$. Why?**

Then using the relation

$$
\frac {1}{2 \omega_k}\delta(p^0 - \omega_k) + \delta(p^0 + \omega_k) = \delta({p^0}^2 - \omega_k^2)
$$

You can obtain the final result, but this is clear to me.

Comment: Hi. What is it that you do not understand exactly?

Comment: I wrote it in bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if the following will help or not, but what is actually happenning here is this:
$$\int dx \Big[f(x)\delta(x+a)+g(x)\delta(x+b)\Big]=
\int dx f(x)\delta(x+a)+\int dx g(x)\delta(x+b)$$
and then in the second integral (and only in the second) we substitute $u=-x$ and then relabell back the dummy variable $u$ to $x$. In all, this results in replacing $x$ with $-x$, switching the integration limits and having an overall sign factor. The latter sign factor can be compensated by switching back the integration limits from $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}$ to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, with the result being
$$\int dx \Big[f(x)\delta(x+a)+g(x)\delta(x+b)\Big]=
\int dx f(x)\delta(x+a)+\int dx g(-x)\delta(-x+b)$$
which is actually equal to
$$\int dx \Big[f(x)\delta(x+a)+g(x)\delta(x+b)\Big]=
\int dx f(x)\delta(x+a)+\int dx g(-x)\delta(x-b)$$

Comment: Well, this perfect in 1D but the situation, using your notation is
$$
∫dx g(x,\vec x) \delta(x+b)
$$
that becomes
$$
∫dx g(-x,-\vec x) \delta(-x+b)
$$
Why also $\vec x$ has to change sign?

Comment: Oh okay. Now I understand your confusion. If one wants to change signs in the three vector momentum $\vec{p}$, one usually performs the substitution $\vec{p}\rightarrow-\vec{p}$ and then the integral $\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}$ goes to $-\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}$ (from $p_x\rightarrow-p_x,\ p_y\rightarrow-p_y$ and $p_z\rightarrow-p_z$ simultaneously) and after switching the three integration limits, the integral wrt the spatial components of the momentum returns to itself... This is how the spatial component substitution is performed.

Comment: The remaining expression is $\vec{p}\rightarrow-\vec{p}$ invariant, as it depends only on the energy

Comment: Now it's clear. Substantially we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\vec x) \,d\vec x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(-\vec x) \,d\vec x
$$